# EXMPP ServerSide Authentication Response

Tags: authentication, erlang, server, xmpp, exmpp

I am currently working on a XMPP-messaging-server and I want to write a response to the client saying I want to initiate a NON-SASL Authentication.
This is the client request I want to process.

```
<<"<stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='example.com' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='username@example.com' xml:lang='en'>">>
```

The problem is, that I don't know how to write a response to the client saying that I want to use Non-SASL Authentication. I am using the EXMPP-library and my server is written in Erlang.

I don't want to use ejabberd because I want to know more about Erlang and XMPP and therefore I don't want to use an out-of-the-box server.

Answer (score 1):

Non-SASL authentication has been deprecated for almost 10 years. Implementing it is not a good idea, there are many clients around that don't support it. SASL PLAIN is only slightly more complicated to implement and supported universally.

If you really do have a good reason to implement it, you can advertise support by including an [`<auth>` element in your stream features](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0078.html#example-9):

```xml
<stream:features>
    ...
    <auth xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth'/>
</stream:features>
```

Comment: Yes I know its deprecated, but it is just for the first prototype.